# Which tense after so that in this case?

Tags: tense

> Could you add this new order to my previous order please, **so that** I won't pay double postage (when I  pay for the item added)

I am wondering which tense will be the best

future, present simple or present progressive

I think future is ok because I won't pay right now.

I don't think present would be ok.

I think that present progressive as future can not fit too since it is not an arrangement.

Am I right?

Comment: All of those tenses are correct and natural, and have the same meaning (assuming that by "future" you mean "will"-future). Surprisingly, it's not natural to use "be going to". I can't explain why any of this is true, or I'd make this an answer.

Comment: English doe not have a future tense. The present tense "so that I won't pay double postage" is fine, though you could also say "so that I don't/won't have to pay double postage".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, present progressive isn't the best choice here, though I could imagine it being used. But a simpler sentence shows that either present or future is used with "so that":

> I put cheese on my dog's pill so that he eats it

OR

> I put cheese on my dog's pill so that he will eat it

BUT NOT

> I put cheese on my dog's pill so that he is eating it